# how to quickly copy between local drives over ssh?

Tags: hard-drive, ssh, external-hard-drive, file-transfer

I've got a server with Ubuntu 15 on it.  I have an external hard drive connected.

I'm trying to copy files the USB drive to the hard drives.  If I do this locally, it's very quick (~30MBi/s).  If I log into the server with ssh and copy from the two mount points, it's very slow (~1.2MBi/s).

I suspect this is due to the encrypted connection, but I'm not sure.  How can I force this transfer to go as fast as I know it can if invoked locally over a remote connection?

Comment: easy test. is your CPU pegged during the transfer? if not, then the crypto is probably not the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically the speed should stay the same as the remotely executed copy command is still executed locally (i.e. the encryption shouldn't be slowing down the copying as only your command is encrypted not the files itself while copying).

How did you measure those speeds? Did you use the exact same command on the exact same files? Copy speeds can vary very easily depending on the actual files and the command (parameters) used.

Comment: Well, both were done by dragging and dropping in Nautilus.  One is a remote connection and the other was local...Both graphical, however.

Comment: Well I sadly can't help you then as I don't know much about how Nautilus is handling copying. But using Nautilus over ssh with X11 forwarding could indeed easily slow things down. Depending on what you're trying to achieve I would recommend you to do this with the cp command (if you need help: "man cp") for example, which should give you consistent results.